# I get the exception "input that isn't a symbolic tensor". Can I convert numpy.ndarray to a tensor?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, computer-vision

I am currently trying to implement ArcFace as loss function for my Inception v4 model. I use a pretrained model from [tensorflow.slim](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/research/slim), which returns the pre-activation logits and endpoints as result as stated in [Inception_v4.py](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/slim/nets/inception_v4.py):

> Returns:
> >>net: a Tensor with the logits (pre-softmax activations) if num_classes
> is a non-zero integer, or the non-dropped input to the logits layer
> if num_classes is 0 or None.
> >>end_points: the set of end_points from the inception model.

I don't know, if I understand the [paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1801.07698.pdf) correctly, but it seems like I could use those logits as input for my ArcFace layer. I can't post a picture, but [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DVEQT.png) is the architecture of ArcFace.
My ArcFace layer looks like [this](https://www.kaggle.com/josealways123/understanding-arcface-and-adacos):

```
from keras.layers import Layer
from keras import regularizers

class ArcFace(Layer):
    def __init__(self, n_classes, s=64.0, m=0.50, regularizer=None, **kwargs):
        super(ArcFace, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.n_classes = n_classes
        self.s = s
        self.m = m
        self.regularizer = regularizers.get(regularizer)

    def build(self, input_shape):
        super(ArcFace, self).build(input_shape[0])
        self.W = self.add_weight(name='W',
                                shape=(input_shape[0][-1], self.n_classes),
                                initializer='glorot_uniform',
                                trainable=True,
                                regularizer=self.regularizer)

    def call(self, inputs):
        x, y = inputs
        x = tf.nn.l2_normalize(x, axis=1)
        W = tf.nn.l2_normalize(self.W, axis=0)
        logits = tf.matmul(x, W)
        if self.m>0:
            logits = self.apply_arcface_margin(logits, y, self.m)
        logits *= self.s
        out = tf.nn.softmax(logits)
        return out

    def apply_arcface_margin(self, cosine_sim, one_hot_labels, arcface_margin):
        theta = tf.acos(cosine_sim, name='acos')
        selected_labels = tf.where(tf.greater(theta, math.pi - arcface_margin),
                                    tf.zeros_like(one_hot_labels),
                                    one_hot_labels,
                                    name='selected_labels')
        final_theta = tf.where(tf.cast(selected_labels, dtype=tf.bool),
                                theta + arcface_margin,
                                theta,
                                name='final_theta')
        return tf.cos(final_theta, name='cosine_sim_with_margin')


    def compute_output_shape(self, input_shape):
        return (None, self.n_classes)
```

When I am running the program I get:

```
Layer arc_face_1 was called with an input that isn't a symbolic tensor. Received type: <class 'numpy.ndarray'>. Full input: [<tf.Tensor 'input_1:0' shape=(?, 1000) dtype=float32>, array([[0., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.],
       ...,
       [0., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.]])].
```

I don't understand the error, cause for me it looks like a tensor. Is there a way to convert the input? If you need further information, just let me know.

I use: 
TF version 1.15 
Keras version 2.3.1 
Python 3.7

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I have tried this code on tf 2.8 and the issue does not exist please upgrade your tf to 2.x version to resolve this.